# How can I follow DRY principles when using Moq to verify function calls in an NUnit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, dry

I have several tests of the following type which verify that a function call to an object will result in corresponding calls to any items that have been added to the object. Is there a way to abstract this into a function, or am I trying to be way too DRY about this?

```cs
[SetUp]
public void InstantiateTesterApp()
{
    t = new TesterApp();
    mock = new Mock<ITestEquipment>();
    t.AddTestEquipment(mock.Object);
}

[Test]
public void OpenEquipmentOpensAddedEquipment()
{
    t.OpenEquipment();
    mock.Verify(eq => eq.Open());
}

[Test]
public void CloseEquipmentClosesAddedEquipment()
{
    t.CloseEquipment();
    mock.Verify(eq => eq.Close());
}
```

Comment: DRY means *Don't Repeat Yourself*, but where's the repetition here?

Comment: I 2nd that - not seeing anything that could be refactored into one method.

Comment: I was thinking something like `VerifyEquipmentCall(() => t.OpenEquipment, "Open")` but now that I'm asking the question out loud, that seems way overzealous. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

For unit test suites where there are many scenarios with similar setups and expectations, I generally find using or replacing the standard unit test `[Setup]` method with a custom factory method for the SUT, or making the SUT and mocks fields on the unit test class, as you seem to have done. Similarly, for the `Assert`s and `Verifies`, the standard success and failure expectations can be refactored into 2 x standard helper methods, e.g.:

```
// Standard Setup helper
private void SetupTesterApp(int someReturnParam, bool someTweak = true, ...)
{
    mockTestEquipment = new Mock<ITestEquipment>();
    mockTestEquipment.Setup(_ => _.SomeMethod()).Returns(someReturnParam);
    mockTestEquipment.SetupGet(_ => _.SomeProperty).Returns(someTweak);
    t.AddTestEquipment(mockTestEquipment.Object);
}

private void VerifyStandardHappyScenario()
{
   Assert.IsFalse(sut.InFaultedStatus);
   mockErrorHandler.Verify(_ => _.HandleError(It.IsAny<Exception>()), Times.Never);
   ... all other standard 'happy scenario' checks
}

... + Similar method for for standard Failure Scenario verifications
```

This allows each UT to be DRY'd up, along the following pattern:

```
[Test]
public void OpenEquipmentOpensAddedEquipment()
{
    // Standard Arrange
    SetupTesterApp(ConstForNormalOperation);

    // Test-Specific setups (possibly overriding the above factory setup)
    mockTestEquipment.Setup(_ => _.AnotherMethod()).Returns(OverriddenValue);

    // Act
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => t.OpenEquipment());

    // Standard Asserts
    VerifyStandardHappyScenario();

    // Specific Asserts and Verifies to this test
    mock.Verify(eq => eq.Open(), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```